# How can unrar a file with python

Tags: python, unzip, unrar

How can I extract a `.zip` or `.rar` file using Python?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Late, but I wasn't satisfied with any of the answers.

```
pip install patool
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive("foo_bar.rar", outdir="path here")
```

Works on Windows and linux without any other libraries needed.

Comment: Good library, but very few flexibility. For example, it cannot overwrite GZ files. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631793/overwriting-previously-extracted-files-instead-of-creating-new-ones

Comment: I tried the above and got `patoolib.util.PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z),` If I am understanding it correctly, I need to have one of the utilities, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 23):

Try the [`pyunpack`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyunpack) package:

```
from pyunpack import Archive
Archive('a.zip').extractall('/path/to')
```

Comment: does it require `patool` or some othrs ?

Comment: yes without it only zip files can be extracted. look in the pyunpack documentation the link I provided there is everything

Answer (score 13):

After some deep diving, here are my findings:

- RAR is not an free open format and is owned by RARLabs. You must install their DLL or exe first to work with RAR. Some programs like 7zip might already include this with them.
- `patool` is application that provides uniform command line as wrapper to other external compression applications. Natively, it can only deal with TAR, ZIP, BZIP2 and GZIP without needing external support.
- `pyunpack` is Python library that can only deal with zip natively but provides interface to `patool`.

**With this in mind, following things worked for me:**

- Make sure 7zip is installed
- `pip install patool pyunpack`

Then to use it,

```
import pyunpack

pyunpack.Archive(archive_file).extractall(extract_dir)
```

Answer (score 12):

A good package for it is `rarfile` :

Here is an example:

```py
import rarfile

rf = rarfile.RarFile("myarchive.rar")
for f in rf.infolist():
    print(f.filename, f.file_size)
    if f.filename == "README":
        print(rf.read(f))
```

Infos and docs here :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/

https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: If you decided to use `rarfile` you might have a problem when trying to extract a file.
This is because the extraction is using the UnRaR.exe tool from winrar website (http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm).
Direct link for windows: http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarw32.exe.
Make sure to have this file. 
I put it in `C:\Python27\UnRar.exe`.
Edit the file: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rarfile.py` like that:
`UNRAR_TOOL = r"c:\python27\unrar.exe"`

It helped me.

Comment: No, it needs `unrar.exe` which is not available on Linux

Comment: @MaksymGanenko: On Linux it needs the `unrar` executable, which can be installed using the package manager. On Debian/Ubuntu it's `sudo apt install unrar`

Comment: for listing archive member names it doesn't require `unrar`, however, to extract and update it is required. You can have the open source program `unar` instead of `unrar` as a backed as well.

Comment: For windows it worked perfect for me, but the other packages introduced in the other answer didn't.

Answer (score 4):

This method only requires having 7zip installed.
Works flawlessly on every system 7zip does.
No python packages needed at all.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('7z x -oOutdir archive.rar')
```

The subprocess module is comes with python.