# Unrar a file with python without relying on unrar.dll

Tags: python, compression, zip, rar

Here [How can unrar a file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614467/how-can-unrar-a-file-with-python) we can see that some modules can be useful for extracting `.rar` files. But it seems that :

- `rarfile` module needs `unrar.dll`
- `pyunpack` also needs some others things (`patool` ?)

**Is there a crossplatform module that doesn't need any external module/.dll that can extract `.rar` files ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The RAR archive format is a bit odd in the sense that it has never got wide adoption. For archive formats like ZIP and GZIP, you have native support almost anywhere. RAR has always been the odd one out.

My suggestion is to create helper code which tries to load both modules and which prints a nice error message when both fail explaining to the user what she can do to fix the problem.

For Linux: "Use you distribution's package manager to install the command-line tool 'rar' or 'unrar'."

Comment: Thank you.  What do I need to provide then ? `unrar.dll` for PC Windows. What file should I provide for Mac or Linux ?

Comment: I don't have a Mac but on Linux: "Use you distribution's package manager to install the command-line tool 'rar' or `unrar`."

Comment: RAR is proprietary and licensed, and the license forbids other implementations.  That is why it never got wide adoption.

Comment: Also patool doesn't natively handle RAR.