# Unzip RAR file - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to unRAR a folder and then move the files in the RAR file to different folders.

I am running in to an issue when trying to unRar the Files.   Here is what I am currently looking at.

```
import patoolib, os
file = 'C:\\mydocuments\RCExport.rar'
file_path = 'C:\\Users\my_folder'
patoolib.extract_archive(file, outdir= file_path)
```

When I run the 4th line - I get the error:

```
PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z)
```

Which I dont understand because there is clearly a rar file in my file path.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify a bit, what is the absolute path of your `rar` file?

Comment: file = 'C:\\mydocuments\\RCExport.rar'

Comment: It's not complaining that it can't find your data file, it's complaining that it can't find a program that can extract it. You'll need to install one.

Comment: Thanks @glibdud  any recommendations?

Comment: Not really, I don't deal with RAR files. But the error says "candidates are (rar,unrar,7z)", so something that provides one of those.

Comment: https://github.com/wummel/patool says: _It relies on helper applications to handle those archive formats_. So, you will need to install a helper application to handle rar. The output given above already suggests suitable candidates. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178369/

Comment: @PatDoyle 7zip is a good free option to extract rar files. (7z)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can unrar a file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614467/how-can-unrar-a-file-with-python)

Comment: It is wierd - I just realized that I have 7zip on my machine - which is weird that patool is not finding it. @ChristianScillitoe