# How can unrar a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to unrar a file in Windows 10 and Jupyter notebook

```
unrar e UCF101.rar Videos/
```

I get the below error:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-6e1cee4de7a2>", line 1
    unrar e UCF101.rar Videos/
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614467/how-can-unrar-a-file-with-python

Answer (score 0):

See this link: https://pypi.org/project/unrar/ and install "python-unrar" from the steps mentioned and that's it.

Comment: i have already install unrar using pip install unrar