# How to extract a multi-volume RAR archive file with a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rar, winrar

I want to do this on Linux with `rar x filename`.

The RAR archive file is split into parts, for example:

```
Filename-001.rar
Filename-002.rar
Filename-003.rar
```

I wanted to extract them all at once with a Python script.

Comment: `WinRAR.exe` and `Rar.exe` are __shareware__. So the users of your Python script would need to purchase a license to use the two executables. `UnRAR.exe` is freeware like `UnRAR.dll`. The source code to extract RAR archives is even open source, see [WinRAR and RAR archiver addons](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm). A multi-volume RAR archive is extracted automatically completely on using `UnRAR.exe` with command `e` or `x` on first volume `Filename-001.rar`.

Comment: `UnRAR.exe` automatically finds out on Windows that `Filename-001.rar` is just the first volume of a multi-volume archive on running `UnRAR.exe x Filename-001.rar` and extracts all files and directories in multi-volume RAR archive from `Filename-001.rar` and `Filename-002.rar` and `Filename-003.rar`. `UnRAR` is also available for Linux for free and although I don't know it for sure as not using Linux, I suppose the Linux versions of `UnRAR` work like `UnRAR.exe` for Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways:

- make a shell (such as `bash`) script to do this. There are many ways to do this that you can find with a Google search, so I'm not going to link them and limit you to one.
- use Python to run shell commands: look into `os.system` and "subprocesses"
- many Python solutions here: [How can unrar a file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614467/how-can-unrar-a-file-with-python)